How do I truncate strings with Humanizer without any suffix added?
Is there any way to use Humanizer to get a result similar to this one? I don't want anything added (like ...) to the right of my string.

Humanizer.Core has a Truncate . method where is the explain more please

You just need to use an empty truncation string:
"Long text to truncate".Truncate(10, "");

